# Changing <style>'s innerHTML for adding new style lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a solution for my problem, but im looking for a more efficient way to solve it.

I basicly want to code a function, that adds new lines of styles in css with Javascript.

My solution is this.

```
function addStyle(newStyleLine){
var mainStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0];
mainStyle.innerHTML = mainStyle.innerHTML + "body {"+newStyleLine+"}";
}
```

And i have a `<style>` tag in my html. It works fine, but i think when i will have a bigger css in the `<style>` it will not be that efficient.

Does anybody have thoughts about a better way to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `getElementByTagName` works fine? Probably, you mean `document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0]`.

Comment: What do you mean by `bigger css`?

Comment: @Oriol im actually using getElementById and have a id for my style, but i was making it more simple for the question, my mistake. I edited it.

Comment: Why u want to append style tag with extra CSS dynamically?

Comment: @HashemQolami i think i will get so many lines of code inside this `<style>` tag. Like 2-5k of lines.

Comment: @Zword I'm trying to write a 2d game in JS, i want a function to create div elements in and give them styles whenever i want. I actually thought about using like `getElementById("IDofElement").style.thing = "asdasd";` but i want to be able to use every css code.

Comment: You should describe the context and the original problem *in the question itself*. Any efficiency considerations depend on what you are really doing. From the comments, it seems that you should look for approaches that just set element properties with classes and dynamically change the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the methods built in that allow you to add new rules to the stylesheet.

**Syntax**

```
stylesheet.insertRule(rule, index)
```

**Parameters**

- **rule** is a DOMString containing the rule to be inserted (selector and declaration).
- **index** is a unsigned int representing the position to be inserted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Do you have any idea how this works behind? I mean what is the algorithm behind his, are we sure it is more efficient way than my solution?

Comment: Test it out and find out.

Comment: Tested, my function for 1 line adding, worked in 0.19 ms, for 1k line addings, worked in 501.75 ms. This method worked in 0.06 ms for 1 adding. And worked in 6.30 ms for 1k addings. It's a big efficiency. I still wonder the algorithm behind this method.